# Open sets on a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Given a metric space $\textbf{R}^{2}$ and the subset $S = \{(x,y)\in\textbf{R}^
{2}\mid x + y = 1\}$, how do you find if it is open or not?

I know that, for a subset of a metric space to be open, every element of it must contain an open ball entirely contained in the subset. But how do you relate this to the question being asked.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what the set actually represents first. You can think of $S$ as the graph of the line $y=1-x$. By thinking of it this way it should be clear that you can't draw open balls around any point on the line that stay on the line - any ball must contain points that lie off of the line.

For a concrete example, take $(x,y)=(0,1)$. For any ball of radius $\varepsilon>0$ around $(0,1)$, the point $(0,1+\varepsilon/2)$ will be contained in $B\big((0,1),\varepsilon\big)$, but this is not a member of your set $S$, since $1+\varepsilon/2\neq 1-0$ for any $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: got it thanks. But what if x+y <1 or x+y>1. I know this question is too silly. But I am new to analysis & I am trying to understand it completely.

Comment: The sets $S_<=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x+y<1\}$ and $S_>=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x+y>1\}$ are both open sets. For these sets you can explicitly construct an open ball around any point $(a,b)$ in $S_<$ or $S_>$ that is contained in the set, i.e. each point in the open ball is also an element of $S_<$ or $S_>$.